# How to remove additional characters in JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have below Code :

```
 ProductDto newProduct = new ProductDto() { Id = 2, Name = "Pixel xl",Price = 2000};
```

Then I serialize by below code and save it in database:

```
private static string ToJson(object model)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings jsonWriter = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    };

    var type = model.GetType();
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo item in type.GetProperties())
    {      
        var propName = item.Name;

        var propValue = item.GetValue(model);
        if (propValue == null) continue;

        propValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propValue, Formatting.Indented, jsonWriter);

        dic.Add(propName, propValue.ToString());
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);
}
```

The result in database is like below :

> {"Id":"2","Name":"\"Pixel xl\"","Price":"2000"}

so when I read that string and Desialize it I have below value for Name :

`\"Pixel xl\"` Instead : `Pixel xl`

I want to compare those like this but beceasue of "\ they are not same.

```
// newValue is "Pixel xl";
// oldValue is "\"Pixel xl\"";

if (!Object.Equals(newValue, oldValue))// this line always return true
{
  // do somethid if they are not same 
}
```

Comment: do you mean it is being saved in the database with `\"` values?

Comment: @JericCruz I mean Whan I featch it from db I dont need `\"` beacuse I want to compare it with another string

Comment: that will be never true since you are comparing it by reference

Comment: Use [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

**First:**

It seems that you are using wrong comparison expression. By using `Object.Equal` you are telling that `newValue` and `oldValue` has the same object. They have the same "values" but not same "object".

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method
>   tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method
>   is equivalent to a call to the [ReferenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Reference
>   equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to
>   the same object.

**Second:**

The converted value has an extra double qoute `\"`. You can manually removed that by using `.Replace("\"", "")`. You might want to create another comparison expression to compare your values.
Something like:

```
if (newValue.Name == oldValue.Name && newValue.Id == oldValue.Id && newValue.Price == oldValue.Price)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Same");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Same");
}
```

Sample code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/mJgRsL

**A side note:**

You can refer to this link for the difference of Value vs Reference type object.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx